# Is there going to be support for a native Windows Development environment?

Tags: development, windows

Is there a plan or is it already possible to run the EOS dev environment on Windows?

The only thing I have found about this topic is this link where they are using Ubuntu for Windows to make it possible to develop under Windows:
https://steemit.com/eos/@tokenika/installing-and-running-eos-on-windows

Comment: Seems unlikely for now. There are a couple issues addressing this on GitHub one closed (most recent):
https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/2220?ref=tokendaily and one that's still open (but older):
 https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/1535 I'd probably just follow those for possible updates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EOSIO currently supports the following operating systems:

- Amazon 2017.09 and higher
- Centos 7
- Fedora 25 and higher (Fedora 27 recommended)
- Mint 18
- Ubuntu 16.04 (Ubuntu 16.10 recommended)
- MacOS Darwin 10.12 and higher (MacOS 10.13.x recommended)

Windows is not supported at the moment and no announced plans to support it in the nearest future.

Comment: Though using a VM on windows is quite simple to setup, and keeps the environment nice and clean.

Comment: Running on Docker is also an option. https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/45fb92182ac004416355e38303d1d7770b831dd6/Docker/README.md

Answer (score 2):

You can use Docker like bob_cobb mentioned.

What you need is Windows 10 (Enterprise, Professional oder Education) with Hyper-V and a 64-bit system. Older Versions rely on VirtualBox if this doesn't fit. Here is a [tutorial to activate](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2087-hyper-v-virtualization-setup-use-windows-10-a.html) Hyper-V on your machine.

Then you can [install docker](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/) and follow the steps for [EOS from GitHub](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/tree/master/Docker) wiki.

Comment: I found hyper-v annoying, the simple lack of easy cut/paste between host and guest OS in 2018 seems silly.  Went back to virtualbox